# Help for Mathematics High school

Tags: reference-request, education

I'm looking for mathematics books, courses + exercises for high school level. My daughter was high school certificated but she has stopped her studies for 5 years. She would like to be involved in new educational program but she needs to restore her mathematic capabilities.

Could you help me to identify which mathematics books can help her?

Thanks a lot for your reply,

FR.

Comment: Up to what level did she study in high school? Some high schools do not go much further than elementary algebra, yet others go through calculus and beyond in great detail!

Comment: I recommend you contact your local high school. People there should be in the best position to answer your question.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/)? They have loads of high school and undergraduate material.

Answer (score 5):

I am currently facing the same situation as your daughter only I have taken up mathematics more than 20 years after leaving high school and am currently working through these resources 
http://www.mathtutor.ac.uk/ and http://www.saylor.org/majors/math/ in preparation for college math. hope this helps;)

Answer (score 3):

Many books are there which you may find interesting such as Gödel, Escher, Bach by Douglas R. Hofstadter, Hofstadter's "Metamagical Themas",The Elements Book I to VI by Euclid.you may see the discussion about good books here [What was the book that opened your mind to the beauty of mathematics?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/832223/what-was-the-book-that-opened-your-mind-to-the-beauty-of-mathematics)

Comment: While I absolutely adore GEB (my copy is kept together by ductape and good faith by now), I don't think it's the right book for someone who's trying to "restore mathematical capabilities" - it's not a book that teaches you how to do high school math.

Answer (score 1):

[Playing](http://euclidthegame.neocities.org/) [any](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598310/math-games-for-car-journeys/617328#617328) mathematical [games](http://m.youtube.com/index?&desktop_uri=%2F#/watch?v=7g8pmwLuZxM) might be [effective](http://www.maa.org/external_archive/devlin/LockhartsLament.pdf), including Sudoku [and related games](http://www.calcudoku.org/). She might enjoy [vihart's videos](http://m.youtube.com/#/user/Vihart). You're welcome to introduce your daughter to this site too.

You can't go far wrong with the books of [Simon Singh](http://simonsingh.net/). They'll help get her enthusiastic.

Also, I'd show her some [proofs](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_proof): the best explain *why* things are true and justify various algorithms.